# remove/replace/gsub all words matching list in df (size 6001) from df (size 29175) in r, different size dataframes

Tags: r

i have been trying to remove any words in dfmedia (size 29175) matching any contained in dfvocab (size 6001).

```
dfmedia: each row is a sentence of words in chinese. 
我喜歡吃蘋果; 我愛吃饅頭; 我不喜歡菠菜; 我最討厭蘋果！；我很愛菠菜啊；哪個中國人敢不喜歡饅頭？；哎呀饅頭蘋果菠菜都是食物管人家喜歡否？

dfvocab: 蘋果，饅頭，菠菜

desired result: 我喜歡吃; 我愛吃; 我不喜歡; 我最討厭！；我很愛啊；哪個中國人敢不喜歡？；哎呀都是食物管人家喜歡否？
```

i don't think the results will be any different in chinese or english since it is a simple match and remove/replace, but i'm including the chinese here just in case since my og data is chinese.

I have tried gsub(), mapply(), and using stringr to bind dfmedia and dfvocab together into one dataframe/removing. however since dfvocab and dfmedia are different sized, I am unsure how to approach this with the suggested methods online.

any help would be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward with `gsub`. Just `paste0` all the vocab together with the regex OR operator and replace with `""`

```
> gsub(paste0(dfvocab, collapse="|"), "",  dfmedia)
[1] "我喜歡吃"                 " 我愛吃"                  " 我不喜歡"                " 我最討厭！"              "我很愛啊"                 "哪個中國人敢不喜歡？"    
[7] "哎呀都是食物管人家喜歡否"
```

(I do not speak or read Chinese.) I imagine with such a large vocab set to be deleted you might need to break the 6000 vocab words in chunks and I suspect it will be slow. You might want to look at the `tm` package since text mining might a task that would require such operations to be optimized.

Here's a way to build a reproducible example:

```
> dfmedia <- scan(text="我喜歡吃蘋果; 我愛吃饅頭; 我不喜歡菠菜; 我最討厭蘋果！;我很愛菠菜啊;哪個中國人敢不喜歡饅頭？;哎呀饅頭蘋果菠菜都是食物管人家喜歡否", what="", sep=";")
Read 7 items
> 
> dfvocab <- scan(text="蘋果,饅頭,菠菜", what="", sep=",")
Read 3 items
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the comment. i tried gsub(paste0) but with such a large vocab it kept running into errors. this code worked very well for me from the library(dqap) package for any future users who come across this problem: mgsub(vectordictionary, "", column). mgsub takes out any words in column that match any words in vectordictionary, much more straightforward than gsub. Mac users need to make sure java and jpk are downloaded before using the dpaq package tho.

Comment: Another option, found by searching on "[r] remove stopwords" might be to use pkg:quanteda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48571783/customized-stopword-list-remove?r=SearchResults&s=2|53.0005